# VB.Net File.Copy/File.Move with different credentials

Tags: vb.net, impersonation, .net

Ideally I'd like to be able to copy/move between an accessible folder on my local drive and a network share that I don't have permission to access (but the application would).

I am using impersonation to give me access to the files in the network share but using System.IO File.Move or File.Copy forces me to use the same credentials for each location. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you could do is something like this.

1. Do the impersonation to allow the selection of files.  Copy the files to a location that the app can get to.
2. Stop the impersonation then have the application copy the file from the temp location to the desired end result.

We have done this before in our applications, it isn't elegant, but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

We've done something similar to what Mitchel Sellers is doing, except that we don't have a location that both identities can read from.  We are reading blocks of data into memory using the local context and writing them out while impersonating the remote user.