# How do I access a network drive through the usual System.IO classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, filesystems, io, network-drive

My software handles multiple operations on files, and I have now finished writing the related functions, using the `System.IO` classes.

I now need to add support for network drives. Using a mapping works very well (although `Directory.GetFiles` is a bit low, and I don't know why), but I'd now like to be able to deal directly with paths such as `\\192.168.0.10\Shared Folder\MyDrive`. Is there any way to handle this type of paths other than mounting the drive to an available drive letter, using the newly generated path, and then unmounting?

Comment: Are you experiencing specific issues? There shouldn't be anything different that you need to do to handle UNC paths vs. mapped drives.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the UNC path (which starts with `\\`) directly in your paths. However, you must account for the credentials for this connection, which can be the tricky part.

There are several approaches:

1. If the remote system is on the same domain or there is a trust relationship between the domains, and the user your program is running as has suitable access, it will "just work".
2. You can shell out and execute the `net use` command (through the Windows `net.exe` program) to make a connection with a specific username and password. Be aware that connection is usable by any program running in the user's session, not just your application.  Use the `/DELETE` command to remove the connection when you are done. The typical syntax is: `net use \\computername\sharename password /USER:domain\username`.
3. You can P/Invoke `WNetAddConnection2` to accomplish the same thing as `net use` without shelling out to `net.exe`. By passing NULL as `lpLocalName`, no drive letter is assigned, but the username and password will apply to subsequent accesses made through the UNC path. The `WNetCancelConnection2` function can be used to disconnect.
4. You can P/Invoke `LogonUser` with the `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` flag followed by an impersonation to add additional remote credentials to your thread. Unlike #2 and #3, the effects on the user's entire session will be a little more limited. (In practice, this is rarely done in favor of the well-known `WNetAddConnection2` solution.)

The following is a sample of how to call `WNetAddConnection2` from VB.NET.

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim nr As New NETRESOURCE
    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK
    nr.lpRemoteName = "\\computer\share"
    If WNetAddConnection2(nr, "password", "user", 0) <> NO_ERROR Then
        Throw New Exception("WNetAddConnection2 failed.")
    End If
    'Code to use connection here.'
    If WNetCancelConnection2("\\computer\share", 0, True) <> NO_ERROR Then
        Throw New Exception("WNetCancelConnection2 failed.")
    End If
End Sub

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure NETRESOURCE
    Public dwScope As UInteger
    Public dwType As UInteger
    Public dwDisplayType As UInteger
    Public dwUsage As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
    Public lpLocalName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
    Public lpRemoteName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
    Public lpComment As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> _
    Public lpProvider As String
End Structure

Private Const NO_ERROR As UInteger = 0
Private Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK As UInteger = 1

<DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function WNetAddConnection2(ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpPassword As String, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function

<DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function WNetCancelConnection2(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fForce As Boolean) As UInteger
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Using normal UNC paths such as the one you mentioned works perfectly for me.  For example:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\192.168.1.116\");
```

Works just fine.  If it doesn't, you probably have a security issue or something.  In which case, you'll have to look into impersonation to get around that.  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710186/vb-net-file-copy-file-move-with-different-credentials) for more on impersonation.

Comment: Cool! In fact my code had a check that trimmed backslashes at the beginning of the path, which caused a bug when I tried this.
Thanks!
CFP.

Answer (score 1):

The UNC path you posted (`\\192.168.0.10\Shared Folder\MyDrive`) is odd.  There is no "drive", such a share behaves as a directory.  You'd use `Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.0.10\Shared Folder")`.