# Copy and Rename File VB Script Not Working For SSIS Script Task

Tags: vb.net, file, ssis, copy, script-task

I am dynamically creating reports using an Excel Template for an SSIS Package.  I am attempting to copy the Excel template and rename it using VB 2010 in Script Task object.

The following is my code:

```
 Public Sub Main()

    Dim sourcePath As String = "\\server\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\FileName_TEMPLATE.xlsx"

    Dim destPath As String = "\\server\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\FileName" + CDate(Date.Today.Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xlsx"


    If File.Exists(destPath) = True Then

        File.Delete(destPath)       'delete existing file'
        File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath)         'copy template file and rename'

    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub

End Class
```

I changed `If File.Exists(destPath) = True Then...` to `If File.Exists(sourcePath) = True...` to see if the `sourcePath` existed and then added a `MessageBox("File doesn't exist")` in an `ELSE` statement to so if even the source file exists and it is returning the `MessageBox` stating

```
"File doesn't exist"
```

The Template file is there and I copied and pasted the address from Windows Explorer window to the `sourcePath` string to ensure path accuracy.

The `sourcePath` is on a different server.

The file is in the source path.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: your file has some illegal chars in it, doesnt it?  `"...Dir3\FileName2/26/2015.xlsx"`

Comment: oops...sorry about that..I noticed that earlier and took out the illegal characters....still saying file doesn't exist...Ill make the edit to the question

Comment: Maybe [a credentials issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352197/how-do-i-access-a-network-drive-through-the-usual-system-io-classes)?

Comment: So...it wasn't working because I had the directory open in which the files existed.  I closed the directory and reran and works now.  In short...idiot move on my part ;)