# Accessing file on remote computer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to open a file on a remote computer. The computer I am trying to access has a Domain/Username/Password that are required. I am unable to find out how to use the credentials to access the file.

I don't have much, but I have this so far.

```
    Dim username = "domain\username"
    Dim Pass = "password "
    Dim path As String = "\\" & FIP & "\C$\Test.log "
    Process.Start(path)
```

I cannot figure out how to incorporate the username/pass into the path to run it.

Comment: Is this winforms? Please tag it properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access a network drive through the usual System.IO classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352197/how-do-i-access-a-network-drive-through-the-usual-system-io-classes)

Comment: What is unique about this? Is this through FTP or just a standard share on another computer within your network and you need to connect with a user other than the one you are logged on with?? Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize ProcessStartInfo object and pass that as parameter to Process.start.

```
Dim path As String = "\\" & FIP & "\C$\Test.log "
Dim RemoteMachine As New ProcessStartInfo(path)
RemoteMachine.UserName = "domain\username"
RemoteMachine.Password = "password"
Process.Start(RemoteMachine)
```