# Get files using UNC Path

Tags: c#, unc

I'm trying to retrieve the list of files of one directory with the following code:

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(source);
```

If i try to retrieve them from a local directory, let's say C:\SomeFolder\
The string array is created correctly.
If i do this on a share (\\someshare\somefolder) the array is not created.

I have to do any aditional step to retrieve from a share?

To test I already gave "Full Control" permission to every users on this share. So I guess is not permissions related.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does any of the following apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352197/how-do-i-access-a-network-drive-through-the-usual-system-io-classes

Comment: Is the first option. I'm working on a domain that have trust relationship with the other, and my user have permissions on both

Comment: @AndreRoque if you have access to that share or your application has access to that share.. then it will work.. why don't you setup a system account for your application and then from there users can run it.. is this a web application || winforms application..? if so then you have to have the IIS_USER granted permissions to that shared drive.

Comment: it's a Windows Forms application. There's a way to force login/password to access that share throw the application?

Answer (score 1):

Simple question:

Have you tried your source string with @"\share\directory\folder" ?

Alternatively use source string with "\\share\directory\folder"

It worked for me....

Hope it helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

There might be now files in this directory. Try below

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```